# Tail logs and use grep to exclude specific lines

Tags: grep, tail

I have this line that appears every minute in my log file:

```
2016-03-29 21:52:46,226 INFO     200 GET /api/ping (0.0.0.0) 0.34ms
```

I want to `tail` this log file without showing these lines.

I tried:

```
tail -f log.txt | grep -v "ping"
```

Comment: Do you mean that what you tried don't work?

Comment: The solution has been written a couple of times in the context of other shell commands. You should look for "stdbuf" in the upper right corner of this web page.

Comment: What is the problem? Just tried this on my machine and it works as expected. `echo "..GET /api/ping (0.." | grep -v "ping"` yelids a 1 result with no matches.

Comment: @MattClark echo sthing is easy because its output is finished and flushed. A continuous pipe means buffering which is usually a friend but when waiting for the buffer to fill and flush means an impact on the process, it's an ugly enemy. Luckily, it can be tamed with stdbuf among a couple of options.

Comment: even still, `tail -n 0 -f test | grep -v "ping"` and run this in another terminal `echo "..GET /api/ping (0.." >> test` still result in no output. I've tested this on 4 different unix distros, and cygwin on windows. All have the same expected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
tail -F ~/Your.log | while read LINE;do

if [[ ! "$LINE" =~ "ping" ]]; then

   echo $LINE 

done
fi
done
```